# Change highlighted tab as scrolling in Bootstrap effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to implement the an effect displayed on the example Twitter Bootstrap page.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html

As you scroll down the page the highlighted tab changes based on how far down the page you are.(Global styles, Grid System, Fluid Grid System, ect.).

How is this effect achieved and how can I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a twitter bootstrap plugin called [ScrollSpy](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy) at play that you can implement in your project by following the example given on the documentation page.